# Flutter and Fire Storage: how to actually download files with notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I'm in the process of making an app that - besides several features - is able to list and download PDF files stored in Firebase Storage. Something simple, really.

I can easily retrieve the list of items from a folder inside my bucket (e.g. "myFolder"). I decide to show such list in a `ListView`, with some `ListTile`s.

I followed the documentation's [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#downloading-files) on how to download files. The thing is... when I implement that snipped, nothing happens in my app! For example, I was expecting a download notification bar on my Android Emulator to appear, somewhere.

Here's my ListTile code:

```
...
onTap: () async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File downloadToFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/download-document.pdf');

  await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('/myFolder/myUser/myFile.pdf')
      .writeToFile(downloadToFile);
},
...
```

The only message my console receives is the following:

```
W/NetworkRequest( 9067): No App Check token for request.
```

I'm confused, since I can't find literally ANYTHING clear [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter%20show%20download%20notification&oq=flutter%20show%20download%20notification&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i22i29i30l2.11780j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), besides a ton of outdated / unmaintained packages. I guess the download actually happens, but.. how can I show a download notification for the user when this event occurs?

What is the go-to solution / official supported package that *actually* solves this problem? Where can I read about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking [how to show a notification](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+show+notification?) Or [how to open a local file](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+open+a+local+file&oq=flutter+open+a+local+file)?

Comment: I'd like to show a notification when the download ends, since IT SEEMS that the file is downloaded locally, but I have no idea if that's actually true. I mean, I could even explore how to open the PDF inside the application at that point, for what matters, either way is fine. Thanks for your google queries, I'll explore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flutter Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) to handle downloads with notifications.

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```

Comment: Hi there, for some reason this package doesn't work. I tried this before asking my question, but it throws weird Java.io exceptions.